# GET 404 not found jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, controller

For an input on an JSP- i want to show suggestions relating to the input.

My controller-

```
@GetMapping(value = "/customerAutoComplete")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> customerAutoComplete(@RequestParam(value = "term",
            required = true, defaultValue = "") String term){
        List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();
        ls.add("L110");
        ls.add("L111");
        ls.add("L011");
        return ls;

    }
```

JSP page-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#customerCode").autocomplete({
                source: "/customerAutoComplete",
                minLength:2
             });
         });
</script>
//input somewhere in the file-
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="customerCode" class="font-weight-bold ">Customer#</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customerCode" id="customerCode" required oninput="customerf()"/>
</div>
```

I am currently on the page-
http://127.0.0.1:8080/Project-SNAPSHOT/loanDisbursalForm

I have tried changing the get mapping value to -"/loanDisbusralForm/customerAutoComplete"
but still no luck.

Exact error-

```
jquery-3.5.1.js:10099 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/customerAutoComplete?term=L1 404 (Not Found)
```

**Note-**
When i loading the loan disbursalForm i am also getting this error dont know it has some connection with it or not-

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/Project-SNAPSHOT/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using proper versions of jquery and especially jquery ui solved the issue.

Comment: I have a similar situation , but the jquery function is not calling the controller function, in controller you have a variable 'term', how is that being passed from jsp?

Comment: What was the version of jquery-ui and jquery solved your issue? Please post the exact version with your answers

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> @rinilnath

Comment: Thanks, but all these links are broken now ! And there is no Jquery-ui in it as you mentioned that did the trick, was it not needed ?